# bijection between the set of birational maps and the set of k-algebra homomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, birational-geometry

I am self studying some basic level of algebraic geometry.

**Theorem:** **For any two varieties $X$and $Y$ there is a bijection between:**

**(i)the set of dominant rational maps from $X$ to $Y$ and**

**(ii)the set of k-algebra homomorphisms from $K(X)$ to $K(Y)$**

I am kind of confused by the proof. It is claimed **since any variety has an open cover by affine varieties. Then we can assume $Y$ is affine.** It is also claimed that **we can assume $Y$ is closed.** I did not find this trivial and I don't quite see it.